# How to return bash script exit code to ARM template?

Tags: bash, shell, azure, azure-rm-template

I have a bash script called vm.sh and it will call the vm-template.json file which contains the type `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions` and from that template I called another bash (main.sh) script using **commandToExecute** and the main.sh file will call another sh file (sub.sh) and from there I returned exit code as 1 but it doesn't reflect in the vm.sh which returns the exit code as 0

**vm.sh**

```
az group deployment create --name "$DEPLOYMENT_NAME" --template-file "$TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH"
```

**template.json**

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/test')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('vmTemplateName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
                "type": "CustomScript",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "forceUpdateTag": "v.1.0",
                "settings": {
                   "fileUris": ["[parameters('initScriptURL')]"]
                },
                "protectedSettings":{
                    "commandToExecute": "[concat('bash main.sh', ' ', parameters('name'))]"
                }
            }
        }
```

**sub.sh**

```
type -p <package>

subScriptExitCode="$?"

if [ "$subScriptExitCode" -ne 0 ]; then
    return 1
fi
```

**main.sh**

```
source "sub.sh"

subScriptExitCode=$?

log "subScript ExitCode: $subScriptExitCode"

if [ $subScriptExitCode -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $subScriptExitCode
fi
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure you are providing a lot of unnecessary information. you want your template deployment to return non zero exit code if it failed or?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry about that, all I need is if the package (check the package with type in sub.sh) doesn't found then I need to send the exit code 1 to the vm.sh

Comment: well, so if the script extension returns non zero exit code deployment fails, this should work if you catch exception in sub and main scripts

Comment: Why don't you return the return code of `type` itself? `type -p <package>; return $?` Hopefully there are no statements in `sub.sh` between `type` and capturing the return code `$?`. Similarly in `main.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the shell option `set -e`

Instead of explicitly doing all your checks for `$?`, setting `set -e` at the beginning of your scripts will cause them to exit immediately if any command exits with a non-zero status.

For each of your `.sh` files, just add this line before any other commands (after the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (or similar shebang)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
...
```

If you want logging you can use `trap`s to do it.  For example:

(just remove `sub.sh`, and) edit `main.sh` to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e 

onError() {
  log "command check exit code: $1"
}

trap 'onError $?' ERR

command -v <package>
```

*NB:* `command -v` is more portable than `type -p`